# как решить проблему с clion?

Tags: c++, clion, arm

Я подключил FLTK к СLion. Устанавливал через homebrew. Компилятор выдает следующие ошибки при пересборке CMakeList.
CMakeList:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(fl)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(FLTK_BASE_DIR /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fltk/1.3.8_1)

include_directories(${FLTK_BASE_DIR}/include)

link_directories(${FLTK_BASE_DIR}/lib)

target_link_libraries(fl fltk fltk_images fltk_forms fltk_gl fltk_jpeg fltk_png fltk_z fltk_shared)

add_executable(fl main.cpp)
```

Ошибки:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "fl" which is not built by this
  project.
FAILED: build.ninja
```

Нет идей вообще как исправить, только вливаюсь в программирование.

Comment: Нужно сначала определить `target` через `add_executeble`/`add_library` и только затем настраивать параметры(`target_link_libraries`).